# sql query with incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need help with an annidated query, I have to find the 1 rep max( Max(Carico) ) of the exercises "Bench Press" and "Squat" for each User who has been gym member for more than 5 years.

[This is my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRskF.png)

I tried this:

```
    SELECT U.Nome,U.Cognome, MAX(P1.Carico) AS MaxSquat,MAX(P2.Carico) AS MaxBench
FROM utente AS U, scheda AS S1, programma AS P1,scheda AS S2, programma AS P2
WHERE U.CF IN(SELECT U.CF
                FROM Utente U
             WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year))
        AND U.CF=S1.ID_Utente AND S1.ID_Scheda=P1.ID_Scheda
        AND U.CF=S2.ID_Utente AND S2.ID_Scheda=P2.ID_Scheda 
        AND P1.nRipetizioni=1 AND P1.Esercizio="Bench Press"
        AND P2.nRipetizioni=1 AND P2.Esercizio="Squat"
GROUP BY U.Nome,U.Cognome
```

I have this as output:

```
Nome    |Cognome|MaxSquat |MaxBench|
Mario   |lalala |   100   |  200   |
Simon   |jujuju |   130   |  100   |
```

But it doesn't show the tuples with Null values

I'd like to get an output like this:

```
Nome    |Cognome|MaxSquat |MaxBench|
John    |blabla |   90    |  Null  |
Carl    |lasdll |   Null  |  150   |
Mario   |lalala |   100   |  200   |
Simon   |jujuju |   130   |  100   |
```

How can I do that? thank you

Comment: selecting from different tables, specifying the link in the where clause is equivalent to an inner join and returns by definition only the lines with all data present.

Comment: @DirkHorsten so what can I do to get my expected result?

Comment: Be patient and wait till I typed an answer

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

When you state conditions in a **where** clase, you will only get results for which these conditions are true. Specifically, you get what you anked: results with P1.Esercizio="Bench Press" and P2.Esercizio="Squat" (and some other conditions).

What you need is results with either no P1 or one with P1.Esercizio="Bench Press" (and a lot of other contidions)

That is where a left join is made for: get all lines from the first table specified and only those from the second that can be matched. Move **ALL** the conditions that apply to tables that are allowed to be absent after the **on** keyword of the join clause

You can put left joins in serious and write this

```
SELECT U.Nome
     , U.Cognome
     , MAX(P1.Carico) AS MaxSquat
     , MAX(P2.Carico) AS MaxBench
FROM   utente AS U
     left join scheda AS S1 on U.CF=S1.ID_Utente 
     left join programma AS P1 on S1.ID_Scheda=P1.ID_Scheda 
          AND P1.nRipetizioni=1 AND P1.Esercizio="Bench Press"
     left join scheda AS S2 on U.CF=S2.ID_Utente 
     left join programma AS P2 on S2.ID_Scheda=P2.ID_Scheda 
          AND P2.nRipetizioni=1 AND P2.Esercizio="Squat"
WHERE U.CF IN(SELECT U.CF
            FROM Utente U
         WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year))
GROUP BY U.Nome, U.Cognome
```

I did not test this code. If you can't get it running, feel free to mention this in a comment and I will take it up again.

Comment: @LucaPearl, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  Marking questions as "checked" indicates solved and others encountering similar can easily look at answers that worked similar to their issues.  It also prevents others from trying to offer answers to questions already resolved.